# What does libsignal use the registrationId for?

Tags: encryption

I am playing around with the libsignal at the moment and i was noticing that in the different documentation for [libsignal-js](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-javascript) or [libsignal-java](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-java) one of the first steps is always to generate a so called "RegistrationId" which is basically a (nearly) random 16bit int:

```
var registrationId = new Uint16Array(Internal.crypto.getRandomBytes(2))[0];

return registrationId & 0x3fff;
```

In the rest of the examples this registration id is never used again so my question is:

- Do I have to generate this id and if yes what is it for?

I am aware that every user needs an index to find the keys afterward, but I don't get why to generate a random number of this length which could lead to collisions quite fasten (with 14 bits effective entropy).

Comment: Did you [search](https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-javascript/search?q=generateRegistrationId&unscoped_q=generateRegistrationId) the source code?

Comment: Sure but it also only says that it produces an integer but not what its used for...